# Combine privileged users array with my current query

Tags: wp-query, query

I have a custom page template with the following query. Isotope filers my categories and all this works fine. I want now to make this page only viewable by a few **specific**,  **currently logged in authors**. *Example: Posts are only visible to an author with one of these ID's (1,2 or 3) and are logged in.*

```
    <ul id="filters">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">Everything</a></li>
    <?php 
        $terms = get_terms("category"); // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy
        $count = count($terms); //How many are they?
        if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
                echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
                //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
            }
        } 
    ?>
</ul>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=20' ); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="isotope-list">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category" );  //Get the terms for this particular item
    $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
        foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
            $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
        }
    ?> 
    <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item">

        <?php the_title(); ?>

    </div> <!-- end item -->
    <?php endwhile;  ?>
    </div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am able to achieve the privileged user's array using the following method: But I have no idea how to combine this with my query listed above.

```
    <?php
$authors = array( 1, 2, 3 ); // privileged users array
$signed_in_user = wp_get_current_user(); // get current user

// check if singed in user is in authors array
if ( in_array( $signed_in_user->ID, $authors ) ) {
    $query = array(
         'posts_per_page' => 20,
         'author__in' = $authors
     );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $query );
}
?>

<?php if ( $query ) : ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile;?>
<?php else : ?>
This message will be displayed if the signed in user is not in the authors array.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution to help someone in the future:

```
    <ul id="filters">

  <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">Everything</a></li>

  <?php 

        $terms = get_terms("category"); // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy

        $count = count($terms); //How many are they?

        if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:

                echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";

                //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label

            }

        } 

    ?>

</ul>

<?php

$authors = array( 1, 2, 3 ); // privileged users array

$signed_in_user = wp_get_current_user(); // get current user

// check if singed in user is in authors array

if ( in_array( $signed_in_user->ID, $authors ) ) {

$query = array(

         'posts_per_page' => 20,

         'author__in' = $authors

);

?>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $query ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<div id="isotope-list">

  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

    $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category" );  //Get the terms for this particular item

    $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms

        foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 

            $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 

        }

    ?>

  <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item">

    <?php the_title(); ?>

  </div>

  <!-- end item -->

  <?php endwhile;  ?>

  <?php else: ?>

  This message will be displayed if the signed in user is not in the authors array.

  <!-- end isotope-list -->

<?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Thank you Wpquestions.com :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this before your code

```
$authors = array( 1, 2, 3 ); // privileged users array
$signed_in_user = wp_get_current_user(); // get current user

// check if singed in user is in authors array
if ( in_array( $signed_in_user->ID, $authors ) ) :
```

And then this after your code

```
<?php else : ?>
This message will be displayed if the signed in user is not in the authors array.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sanchy, thanks for the help, but would you mind posting your code combined with mine though? I'm getting a blank page. I tried the first code you provided above and then below the filter and still a blank page. Or maybe I should have replaced the last code you gave with my other php endif thingy?

Comment: Do you know PHP? Blank page without errors?

Comment: Yes, a blank page- that's all.

Comment: Well if you know php you'll be able to find out why is the page blank. I can't help you from here

Comment: Not very helpful @sanchy - I'm here to ask for help. The full code is what I need. Not pieces of a puzzle that I have to put together.

Comment: If you can't even place your code inside an IF, you shouldn't be lying saying you know php.
This is not a place where you come to get your homework done. This is a place to share knowledge, learn and become better at what you do.

Comment: Asking someone if they know PHP is like asking someone; "Do you know cooking"? I'm a beginner at PHP. I think it's possible for a novice to NOT know how to use an if statement. Your just being a prick!